# Telerik RadComboBox ItemTemplate and MultipleSelectionBoxTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik

how can i specify MultipleSelectionBoxTemplate which i can access properties of selected items

i have an employee class

```
public class Employee {
public string Firstname {get;set;}
public string Lastname {get;set;}
}
```

I am using Telerik radCombobox in my wpf application to display list of employee

```
            <telerik:RadComboBox x:Name="radComboBox"
                                 Width="200" 
                                 AllowMultipleSelection="True" 
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=EmployeeList}"  
                                 >

                <telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Lastname}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:RadComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

this works fine for itemtemplate  but when i select an item the display text in combobox show name of Employee class not the Lastname
i tried

```
                <telerik:RadComboBox.MultipleSelectionBoxTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Lastname}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:RadComboBox.MultipleSelectionBoxTemplate>
```

i get no result , the combobox displayvalue of selected item is always empty.

i tried another solution

```
                <telerik:RadComboBox.MultipleSelectionBoxTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedItems,Converter={StaticResource SelectionToCustomStringCoverter}}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </telerik:RadComboBox.MultipleSelectionBoxTemplate>
```

this neither work , the converter always execute at first selection

this is really crazy spending 4 hours to figure out a simple thing ,
so my question is how can i specify MultipleSelectionBoxTemplate which i can access properties of selected items .

Comment: In the first case you bind to `Lastname`, in the second `LastName`. Property names are case-sensitive.

Comment: @thatguy actually it was typo in question in my code it is correct . they are both binded to Lastname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this neither work , the converter always execute at first selection

You need to bind to a property that is actually set when the selection changes, such as the `Count` property of the `SelectedItems` collection.

Try using a multi value converter and a `MultiBinding`:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource SelectionToCustomStringCoverter}">
            <Binding Path="SelectedItems" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadComboBox}"/>
            <Binding Path="SelectedItems.Count" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=telerik:RadComboBox}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

You will then get the currently selected items from `values[0]` in the converter.